# Query completed with an empty output

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1033hNIUutMjjdwiZZ40u59Q8DvxBXYr7pcWyRRHAdXk

That's a link to the file in which it is not working! If you open it, go to sheet named "My query stinks".

The sheet called deposits has data like this in columns A (date), B (description), and C (amount):

```
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|   |     A     |        B        |    C    |
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| 1 | 6/29/2016 |      1000000044 |     480 |
| 2 | 6/24/2016 |      1000000045 |  359.61 |
| 3 | 8/8/2016  | 201631212301237 |   11.11 |
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

The sheet "My Query Stinks" has data in columns A (check number), B (failing query) and C (amount):

```
+---+-----------------+------+--------+
|   |        A        |  B   |   C    |
+---+-----------------+------+--------+
| 1 |      1000000044 | #N/A |    480 |
| 2 |      1000000045 | #N/A | 359.61 |
| 3 | 201631212301237 | #N/A |  11.11 |
+---+-----------------+------+--------+
```

In Column B on My Query Stinks, I want to enter a query. Here's what I'm trying:

```
=query(Deposits!A:C,"select A where A =" &  A2)
```

For some reason, it returns "#N/A Error Query completed with an empty output." I want it to find that 1000000044 (the value in C4) matches 1000000044 over on Deposits and return the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=query(Deposits!A:C,"select A where B ='" &A2&"'")
```

Explanation

Values like 1000000044 in Column B of the Deposit sheet and Column A of My Query Stinks sheets are set as text (string) values, so they should be enclosed on single quotes (apostrophes) otherwise QUERY think this values are numbers or variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=query(Deposits!A:C,"select A where B = '"&A2&"' LIMIT 1")
```

**You'll need LIMIT 1** as you have multiple deposits for the same value in your second column.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this problem could be to replace '=' with 'contains':

```
=query(Deposits!A:C,"select A where B contains '" &A2&"'")
```

Simple, but this error cost me half a morning.